# How to create vector from nested for loops in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

may I know whether there's a way to print the results out as a vector from this nested for loop?

```
for(i in 0:3){
  for(j in 1:3){
    print(0.03*(i-1)+exp(-j))
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to print each output? Instead the final list only?

Comment: `rowSums(expand.grid(0.03*((0:3) -1) ,exp(-(1:3))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
i <- rep(0:3, each=3)
j <- rep(1:3, times=4)
0.03*(i-1)+exp(-j)
[1] 0.33787944 0.10533528 0.01978707 0.36787944 0.13533528 0.04978707 0.39787944 0.16533528 0.07978707 0.42787944 0.19533528 0.10978707
```

R is vectorised, so for simple tasks like this there's no need to use loops.

Comment: No need to do "manually" the replication. Use `outer`. Something like: `outer(0:3-1, -(1:3), function(x, y) 0.03*x+exp(y))`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to print it as a vector I imagine you only want to print it once, at the end of the for-loop. What you can do is create an empty vector and fill it with more data for every iteration like so:

```
v <- c()
for(i in 0:3){
  for(j in 1:3){
    v <- c(v, 0.03*(i-1)+exp(-j))
  }
}
print(v)
```

Alternatively you can use `rbind()` instead of `c()` to create a 12x1 matrix instead of a vector

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your format intact and without using `rbind`:

```
output <- c()
k<- 1

for(i in 0:3){
  for(j in 1:3){
    (0.03*(i-1)+exp(-j))-> output[k]
    k<- k+1
  }
}
```

Which will result in:

```
> output
 [1] 0.33787944 0.10533528 0.01978707 0.36787944 0.13533528 0.04978707 0.39787944 0.16533528
 [9] 0.07978707 0.42787944 0.19533528 0.10978707
```